# brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I'm getting several type of problems with most obvious the low speed and low signal. More rarely I'm getting disconnections or the wifi-manager keeps asking for the wireless key (although I'm entering the right one).
Also after suspending there are no networks on network-manager and all selections are grayed out.

Also, in dmesg I have a lot of:

```
brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code (0x30 0x30)
```

and

```
brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
```

Some info about my wireless:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network 

*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:49:0f:fe:d2:81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:137 memory:dd800000-dd807fff memory:dd400000-dd7fffff
```

```
$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0115 (rev 01)
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i firmware  

[    0.204635] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.097705] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[    4.740071] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.848288] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    5.366600] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
```

```
$ sudo iw reg get

country GR: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

```
$ dmesg | grep brcm  
[    4.789150] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.789190] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.789282] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.789283] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[    4.898070] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    5.415080] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[    5.454670] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code (0x30 0x30)
[    5.461671] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   21.069302] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[  566.438491] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[  566.439031] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code (0x30 0x30)
[  575.308208] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[ 1025.706281] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[ 1025.706568] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code (0x30 0x30)
[ 1033.214674] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[ 4092.109113] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[ 4092.110501] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code (0x30 0x30)
[ 4100.966680] brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
[ 6370.214755] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code (0x30 0x30)
```

```
$ lsmod | grep -e b43 -e ssb  
(returned nothing)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of: `sudo iw reg get` and also: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: @chili555 When I ran the second command it told me that the package is not installed and when I installed it I lost networking. Now network-manager says "No network devices available". How can I revert back without internet? (My laptop doesn't have a lan port.)

Comment: @chili555 Ok, I was able to "purge" it and return in the previous status.

Comment: The point of the command was to be certain that the incorrect driver was *NOT* installed and interfering; not to install it. Let's also see: `dmesg | grep brcm` and also: `lsmod | grep -e b43 -e ssb`

Comment: I got similar error: Boot failed with error: `ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: failed to get arp ip table err:-52`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending a lot of time researching how to solve my problem, I realized that the best solution was to change my wireless card with an Intel one.
This way not only I solved my wireless network problems but also my Bluetooth problems.

I know this answer was not what I was expecting, but if I knew it I would have spent the 20$ and 2 minutes to change it a long time ago.

So my advice to anyone that have problems with the wifi of Dell XPS 9550 is to change the wifi card (I used this one: Intel Wireless Dual Band AC 8260NGW 867Mbps WIFI Card Bluetooth 4.2 8265NGW).

I would like also to thank @chili555 for his time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll see if I can get a wifi card replacement on my country. How do you know if it's compatible? (hardware here is kind of expensive)

Comment: @morhook You can find the one I used for under 15$ in eBay or you can check the cards these laptops use: https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?release=18.04%20LTS&category=Desktop&category=Laptop

Comment: Looks like I might travel to United States finally. I'll buy on eBay a new card!!! Thanks @yannis for your comment.