# Boot failed with error: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: failed to get arp ip table err:-52

Tags: boot, 20.04

I checked the similar question [brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894271/brcmf-inetaddr-changed-fail-to-get-arp-ip-table-err-23) . But it does not really give out answer.

Here is my same error: `error: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: failed to get arp ip table err:-52` when booting Linux system.
I can switch to tty2-6 to login user shell. I can connect to wifi network automatically. So I guess it's not hardware problem.
I tried to execute command `startx` under logined root shell. It reports need to wait for x11 been terminated, but my GDM3 and Xorg is not started. This is weird.

Here is my environment info:

- I installed Ubuntu 20.4 on MacBook Pro 2015
- My system should be the latest version system and systemd package version etc.

Does anybody knows solution or hints to figure out this problem's answer?
Can't boot the system got me crazy. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I just got this on an xps 9500 with Ubuntu 20.04.2 while trying to get a docking station working. Exasperating!

Comment: Actually for me it ended up being a distraction: I had changed from integrated to discrete graphics (`prime-select nvidia`) which broke something. I changed back and rebooted: gui came up normally!

Comment: Same for me.  Added Nvidia driver 460 and started getting this error, then hang on boot.  Removed the driver and could boot normally again.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Dell_XPS_9550 running ubuntu_20.04 and I get the exact same error:  … : -52.
My system hangs at boot time with the same error on the console.
The system was working and I believe that error message has always been there, but I never paid attention to it, since I have SSD_nvme_m2 installed, so it boots really fast. As with your case, my WiFi works just fine.

My hanging problem appeared when I tried to get the bluetooth working with airPods.
Note that on most (if not all) laptops the WiFi and bluetooth are on the same chip.

Once, I deleted the changes I made for the bluetooth (setting the ControllerMode=bredr in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf) the system booted just fine, however the ieee80211 …: -52 error message still shows up at boot time, but the system boots and the WiFi works.

Since you say, your WiFi works. I’m thinking your boot problem could be due to the bluetooth as it was for mine. So disable the bluetooth to see if your system boots passed that error message.